# Firebase Android delete node key in ListView on longpress

Tags: java, android, firebase, listview, firebase-realtime-database

Tried to search a lot but after 2 days I'm still stucked on this problem.
I have the following database in my Firebase which is populated in my `ListView`.
For each row in the `ListView` is displayed data1 and data2.

```
 test-3db7e
  |
  +---users
       |
       +---W9KkXAidmHgyOpyeQPeT5YxgQI42
            |
            +---data
            |    |
            |    +----LIv-OeQdixT0q6NZ-jL
            |    |     |
            |    |     +---data1: "Data1"
            |    |     |
            |    |     +---data2: "Data2"
            |    |
            |    +----LIv-R3PRKaEHaAcMjWu
            |          |
            |          +---data1: "Data1"
            |          |
            |          +---data2: "Data2"
            |
            +---name: "The user's name"
```

Until now it all seams ok, I can upload data from my app and the listview syncs perfectly with the Firebase console.

I made the ListView using the folling code:

```
    //Updating the listview
    databaseReference.child("users").child(user).child("data").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            //Getting all the children at this level
            Iterable<DataSnapshot> children = dataSnapshot.getChildren();
            dataArrayAdapter.clear();

            for (DataSnapshot child : children) {

                Data data = child.getValue(Data.class);
                dataList.add(data);
                dataArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Also I created the Data.class to store the values from the previous code to the listview.

```
    package com.mypackge.firebase;

    public class Data {

        private String data1;
        private String data2;

        public String getData1() {
            return data1;
        }

        public void setData1(String data1) {
            this.data1 = data1;
        }

        public String getData2() {
            return data2;
        }

        public void setData2(String data2) {
            this.data2 = data2;
        }

        public String toString() {
            return data1 +"\n"+data2;
        }
    }
```

The problem now is with the following code, on long press on the list view I want to remove (if pressed yes on the dialog) the row that was pressed.

```
     /**
     *
     * Deleting data on long press
     *
     */

    //Creating a dialog interface
    final DialogInterface.OnClickListener dialogClickListner = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

            if(i==DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE){

            //    WHAT TO DO HERE?????

            }else if(i== DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE){


            }

        }
    };

    //Creating the Item on Click Listner
    lstViewData.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
            //Creating the alert dialog
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(adapterView.getContext());
            builder.setMessage("Do you want to delete?")
                    .setPositiveButton("Yes", dialogClickListner)
                    .setNegativeButton("No",dialogClickListner).show();

            //    WHAT TO DO HERE?????

            return false;
        }
    });
```

Thank you all for your time!!!

Comment: Calling `remove()` on a firebase reference deletes it, did you try using that?

Answer (score 0):

The key for solving this problem is to add the `pushed key` that is generated when you are creating an object of `Data` class to the database. So beside `data1` and `data2` fields, add another field named `key` (also of type String). Please also add the corresponding setter and getter for this new field.

Now, this is how you need actually to create on object:

```
DatabaseReference dataRef = databaseReference.child("users").child(user).child("data");
String key = dataRef.push().getKey();
Data data = new Data();
data.setData1("data1");
data.setData2("data2");
data.setKey(key);
dataRef.child(key).setValue(data);
```

Now your `Data` object has the `key` field populated with the actual key from the database. To display the data and to remove a particular object that was clicked, please use the following code:

```
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        ArrayList<Data> list = new ArrayList<>();
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            Data data = ds.getValue(Data.class);
            list.add(data);
        }
        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
        ArrayAdapter<Data> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
        listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext());
                builder.setMessage("Do you want to delete?");

                builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int i) {
                        String key = arrayAdapter.getItem(i).getKey();
                        dataRef.child(key).removeValue();
                    }
                });

                builder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int i) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });

                AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                dialog.show();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
dataRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```