# getValue of database entry onitemClick

Tags: java, android, firebase

I'm having an issue getting the Value of a database entry and passing it to intent.in the following code onItemClick is passing the data of the whole database over as opposed to the item clicked. How can I specify to only pass the data of the item clicked over?? Newbie to Firebase so im at a loss, any help greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the right way of getting data:

```
String title = putData.child("title").getValue(String.class);
```

You cannot call `getValue()` method on a `DatabaseReference` object. In order to get data from the database you need to attach a listener. Everything in Firebase is about listeners. So you should do the exact same thing that you in your first lines of code.

Comment: Sorry Alex, this worked perfectly however its pushing all the data from the database back over as opposed to just those at the item clicked,  I know its something simple to do with the for loop, ive updated the code above to what I have at the minute, Thanks again if you can help

Comment: Oh, I understand now better what you are trying to do. See **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51656064/firebase-android-delete-node-key-in-listview-on-longpress/51657087/)** how you should implement `OnItemClickListener` on your `ListView`. So you'll be able to get the corresponding item on button click, right?